# How can I have two shortcuts to FireFox in dock bar

Tags: 20.04

I want to have two shortcuts to FireFox in the dock bar. However when I pull a second one to the bar, it just replaces the old one and I still have one shortcut!  I want to dedicate one of the Firefoxes to my Jupyter nootbooks and the other for surfing the web, I even prefer for them to have different icons

I mean two icon of Firefox in the left bar:

[image]

Comment: Shortcuts like what? Can you make it more clear?

Comment: @kashish I did in the question!! The picture isn't repeated (like two mirrors in front of each other), I did that for fun!

Comment: @User24601 I know but then I should focus and choose which is which.... But I just want to dedicate one of the firefox for Jupyter nootbooks and the other for Browsering, I even prefer for them  to have different icons

Comment: @User24601 how does that solve the question of having two separate independent Firefox launchers?